# CallKit prevent PushKit from being called

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit, pushkit

I'm using PushKit and CallKit in my iOS app for sending and receiving calls.
My problem is that when app is killed and I receive a call, `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` is called and I display a native call screen using the line

```
provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: currentCallID, update: update, completion: { error in })
```

But once this line is called and native call screen appeared, in case of caller cancel the call, `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` is never called again.

What is strange is that if I commented this line

```
provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: currentCallID, update: update, completion: { error in })
```

`didReceiveIncomingPushWith` is being called perfectly.

Does anyone have any explanation/solution?

> Edit

I'm using XMPP server which has a socket open, in case I close this socket in `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` method it worked (but causes another issue that I couldn't answer as there connection is lost).

Comment: Do you call the supplied completion handler?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling `completion()` of `didReceiveIncomingPushWith `

Comment: Because you are not invoking endCall method.

Comment: I've to receive a notification that caller has cancelled in order to call endCall

Comment: After receiving notification from `PushKit` and displaying native call screen, you should connect with your socket and when you'll get cancelled/end call notification via socket instead of `PushKit`. Just invoke the reportCall with declineElseWhere and dismiss you caller screen.
This will ease you work.

Comment: I think that `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` is not called as long as socket is connected.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas You are right, once socket is connected I receive response that session has been ended so I should deal with it to end the call instead of notification in this case, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you cancel a call/terminal always invoke and tell the system that call has been changed his state with this method.

## Objective-C

```
[provider reportCallWithUUID: currentCallID endedAtDate:endingDate reason:(CXCallEndedReasonDeclinedElsewhere)];
```

## Swift

```
provider.reportCall(with: currentCallID, endedAt: endingDate, reason: .declinedElsewhere)
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to get from the system that the caller has ended the call (before I answer). But `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` is not called!

Comment: No, I switched to using the opened socket connection as you mentioned.